# Piping multiple lines within bash script

Tags: pipe, xargs

I have some complicated logs that I try to parse. What I want is to find a string *H*, get column 5 from the line that matches, and then take all other lines where column 5 matches the line with the string *H*.

**Example input**

```
a b c d 31 1
a b c d 31 H
a b c d 31 2
a b c d 32 1
a b d d 32 2
a b c d 33 1
a b c d 33 H
a b c d 33 2
```

**Expected output**

```
a b c d 31 1
a b c d 31 H
a b c d 31 2
a b c d 33 1
a b c d 33 H
a b c d 33 2
```

So, I have been able to do so by making two separate scripts:
`script1 | xargs -n1 | script2`

**script1** searches for string *H*, and then prints the fifth column.
`cat logfile | grep 'H' | awk '{print $5}'`

**script2** then prints all other lines from the logfile where column 5 matches the output of the first script: 
`cat logfile | awk -v var="$1" '$5 == var'`

I want to make the input file, the logfile, a variable, so that I can use $1 in the script, and then call `script logfile`. But then I must merge the two scripts to one script, because both scripts parse the same logfile. What is, generally speaking, the right approach to do this? I say generally, because I am a newby to bash scripting.

The two problems that I encouter are, firstly: the $1 of the first script (which is the logfile) is different from the $1 in the second script (the number that is the output of the first script) that I pipe to awk. Secondly, I cannot find the equivalent of `xargs -n1` for use within one bash script.

Comment: can you provide a sample of log and expected output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second `awk` reads two inputs, one after the other - from the piped output of the first `awk` and then from the file itself. One way to identify the start of the second input is that `NR` (the **N**umber of the current input **R**ecord, overall) no longer matches `FNR` ( the current **F**ile's record number).  Note that `-` as a FILE arg means tells `awk` to get the data from `stdin` (via a *pipe*, in this case).

```
awk '$6=="H"{print $5}' "$1" |
awk 'NR==FNR{k[$1];next}
     $5 in k{print}' - "$1"
```

---

Note that the above method of identifying the second input is in common use, but fails to behave as expected/desired when there is nothing to read from the first input. For this job's requirements it won't matter if the first imput delivers nothing. The logic will never get past `NR=FNR` where it will build up a list of `k` index value (ie. `$1` from the main file) - but nothing is ever done with them – so the script works with a null imput via the pipe, but only because of a messy side-effect of the particular logic used.

There is however, in GNU awk (`gawk`), a sure-fire way to identify the current file/pipe. There is a special variant to the commandline `FILE` arguments: *"...an argument that has the form var=value, assigns value to the variable var—it does not specify a file at all."* – see: [Other Command Line Arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Other-Arguments.html#Other-Arguments)  The placement of such *var=value* args is significant – values needed for a specific FILE must be placed on the command line *before* its associated FILE – subsequent *var=value* are not applied within `awk` until the preceding files/pipe has been fully read.

Here is the *var=value* version.

```
gawk '$6=="H"{print $5}' "$1" |
gawk 'fn==1{k[$1];next}
      $5 in k{print}' fn=1 - fn=2 "$1"
```

output (its the same for both script versions)

```
a b c d 31 1
a b c d 31 H
a b c d 31 2
a b c d 33 1
a b c d 33 H
a b c d 33 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I have also made improvements with while in combination with read:
`cat $file | awk '/H/ {print $5}' | while read -r id; do cat $file | awk -v var="$id" '$5 == var'; done`